# ¿Cómo validar un entero para que sólo se ingresen números y no letras ni símbolos?

Tags: java, validación, bucles, try-catch

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño programa donde el usuario ingresa dos números, pero si ingresa una letra esto debería de solicitarle de nuevo que ingrese un numero.

No se si ingresar el `do-while` después del `do` que ya esta creado o crear un `try-catch`.

Mis variables son

```
int num1, num2, res;
do {          
    System.out.println("Please , give me your first number");
    num1=scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please , give me a second number");
    num2=scanner.nextInt();

} while();
```

Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: yo me apoyé en este video, te dejo la liga por si te funciona. https://youtu.be/EjGOGn64sCI

Answer (score 0):

En el código publicado se intenta leer desde la instancia `scanner` directamente un entero con el metodo `nextInt` este metodo arrojará una exception de tipo `InputMismatchException` si lo siguiente que lee `scanner` no es un entero.

Si se desea validar se debe leer como cadena, y validar si es un valor valido.

Para el caso consultado se puede declarar un metodo que valide si una cadena es un entero. El metodo hace la validación capturando la exception `NumberFormatException` que se produce si el formato de la cadena no es válido para un entero

```
public static boolean IsInteger(String text) {
    int v;
    try {
      v=Integer.parseInt(text);
      return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
       return false;
    }
}
```

y después se puede hacer uso de este método para validar que una cadena es un entero

```
int num1, num2, res;
String snum1, snum2; //se declaran cadenas para recibir la entrada del scanner
do {          
    System.out.println("Please , give me your first number");
    snum1=scanner.nextLine(); //Se lee la entrada como cadena
} while(!IsInteger(snum1)); //Se sigue pidiendo la entrada si no es entero
num1 = Integer.parseInt(snum1); //Ahora si se parsea a entero
```

para la segunda variable un bucle similar, pero cambiando el mensaje y la variable