# ¿Como valido los datos que se ingresan por teclado a una Matriz en Java?

Tags: java, array, matrices

Estoy empezando a aprender a programar y queria despejar la duda de como puedo validar cada uno de los datos que se ingresa por teclado a una matriz, digamos necesito que se ingresen numeros, pero en un rango de 1 a 50 unicamente, sinceramente no se como hacerlo agradeceria quien pueda despejarme la duda de como realizar esa validacion
mi codigo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Digite el primer numero");
    int N = leer.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Digite el segundo numero");
    int M = leer.nextInt();
    
    int [][] matriz = new int[N][M];
    
    
    
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){    
        for(int j=0; j<M;j++){
            
            System.out.println("Digite el numero");
            
            matriz[i][j] = leer.nextInt();
        }
        
    }
    
    System.out.println("valores introducidos:");
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Revisa la siguiente pregunta :https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/392491/c%c3%b3mo-validar-un-entero-para-que-s%c3%b3lo-se-ingresen-n%c3%bameros-y-no-letras-ni-s%c3%admbolo/392505#392505 quizás en ella encuentres una guía

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de leer el número se puede verificar que esté en el rango correcto. Si no lo está se puede disminuir el valor de la variable `j` para repetir la misma iteración:

```
    matriz[i][j] = leer.nextInt();
    
    // validar que el número esté en el rango
    if (matriz[i][j] < 1 || matriz[i][j] > 50) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese números entre 1 y 50");
    
        // disminuir j para volver a pedir el número en la posición j
        --j;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Era lo que buscaba